# A norm description for singular matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, norms

For $n>2$, are there  norms $\parallel.\parallel_{a}$  and  $\parallel.\parallel_{b}$ on $M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ with the following property:

> $A\in M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ is singular if and only if $\parallel A \parallel_{a}=\parallel A \parallel_{b}$

For $n=2,\;$  these norms are  $\parallel A \parallel_{a}=\sqrt{\sum a_{ij}^{2}}$ and
$\parallel A \parallel_{b}=\parallel.\parallel_{op}$, the operator norm.

Comment: I would try with $\|A\|_a = \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sigma_i^2 \right)^{1/2}$ and $\|A\|_b = \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sigma_i^2 \right)^{1/2}$, where the $\sigma_i$ are the singular values of $A$ in decreasing order. These should be generalizations of the [Schatten norms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schatten_norm), and $\|A\|_a$ defined like this coincides with the one that you have defined $\|A\|_a = \sqrt{\sum a_{ij}^2}$ (Frobenius norm).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Ky_Fan_norms

Comment: @FedericoPoloni  thank you for your comment.

Comment: @MikaeldelaSalle thank you for your comment. with combination of your two interesting comment I got my answer.

Comment: @MikaeldelaSalle One of us should probably write this as an answer, so that this question does not keep getting bumped as unanswered. Want to do it, since you provided the most useful link?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni And I will accept the answer by you or Mikael de la  Salle, with pleasure.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Please, write an answer, you shot first!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(This answer expands the ideas in the comments by Mikael de la Salle and myself).

There is a family of matrix norms that can be defined as follows: given $p \geq 1,k \leq n$,
$$
\|A\|_{p,k} = \left(\sum_{i=1}^k \sigma_i(A)^p\right)^{1/p},
$$
where we denote by $\sigma_i(A)$ the $i$th [singular value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value) of $A$ (taken in nonincreasing order, $\sigma_1(A)\geq \sigma_2(A)\geq \dots$). The most famous examples are the [Schatten norms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schatten_norm) ($k=n$) and the [Ky Fan norms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Ky_Fan_norms) ($p=1$), but they are matrix norms for each $k$ and $p$ (see e.g. [this blog post](http://www.njohnston.ca/2009/08/ky-fan-norms-schatten-norms-and-everything-in-between/) by Nathaniel Johnston and the references included in it).

A $n\times n$ matrix $A$ is singular iff $\sigma_n(A)=0$, and this is equivalent to $\|A_{p,n}\|=\|A_{p,n-1}\|$ for every $p$. So any pair of norms with $k=n$ and $k=n-1$ works.